# Facebook application to like a page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build an application, which uses an [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) reader and connects with Facebook. But when I try to like a page, I send a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) when the *like* box is tapped by the RFID reader. I want the user to [like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) my page as soon as he taps on the *like* box. So now I want to built an application, which accesses the user id and asks the permission to *like* pages on his/her behalf whenever he/she taps on the like box. The action will be performed as follows:-

1. The user taps on a like box.
2. The like box sends an URL (Facebook application URL) with the users id.
3. I receive the action as to *like* the subsequent page.
4. The user now *likes* the page.

I am stuck on the fourth point. How do I make the user like my page?

I am using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that what you're trying to accomplish can't be accomplished. You can't use [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) to "Like" a page. It's not supported in their API. It has to be done using either the Facebook JavaScript or iframe [like buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button).

Answer (score 0):

Generally your app cannot like pages on behalf of user. All you can do is catch FB "like" event (it fires when user likes a page) via javascript and do some custom actions (e.g. postback to a server or smth).
Does that make sense?